# How do I add an image to blogs?

Tags: 7, entities, media

May you give me few hints on how to enable adding 1 optional image to each blog entry?

I've enabled Blog and Image modules and registered users can create and comment on them.

What is the next step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to "Manage Fields" link for the Blog content type (/admin/structure/types/manage/blog/fields) and **add a new field**:
- Name it whatever you want ("blog_picture" or something) and for the **Field Type** select "Image"
- Click "save", pick a default image if you want and click "save field settings"
- On the next screen **do not** tick "Required", make any other changes you want and click "save settings"
- Done!

Comment: It seemed to be good tip. Thanks for the same However it is NOT a traditional way to attach the image (I mean the RTE that provides an inline image placing facility). All what i can do is attaching an image to the post. However, how can I keep it at different places of my post? Any help on this would be highly appreciated. I feel drupal 6 & 7 vary to a greater extent in certain core functionalities. Cheers,
Raghavan alias Saravanan M